# How do I build like functionality using django and djangorestframework?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm using `Django` and `DjangoRestFramework` to build a social media app, and I am having some issues building the functionality for the `like` button on the backend. Here is a walkthrough of my current code and the `error` I am getting:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class Post(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created_at',)

class Like(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='likes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='likes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from apps.feed.models import Post, Like

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        read_only_fields = (
            "id",
            "created_at",
            "created_by",
        )
        fields = (
            "id",
            "created_at",
            "created_by",
            "content",
        )
    
class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Like
        read_only_fields = (
            "id",
            "created_at",
            "created_by",
        )
        fields = (
            "id",
            "created_at",
            "created_by",
            "post"
        )
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets 
from apps.feed.models import Post 
from apps.feed.serializers import PostSerializer, LikeSerializer
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from .models import Post

User = get_user_model()

class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    queryset = Post.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(created_by=self.request.user)

class LikeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = LikeSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)
```

**AddLike.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { addLike, deleteLike } from "./LikeActions";

function LikeButton(props) {
    return (
        <button onClick={props.onClick}>
            Like
        </button>
    )
}

function LikedButton(props) {
    return (
        <button onClick={props.onClick}>
            Liked
        </button>
    )
} 

class AddLike extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            like: false
        }
    }

    onChange = e => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    handleAddLike = () => {
        const like = {
            like: this.state.like
        };
        this.setState({like: true})
        this.props.addLike(like);
    };

    handleDeleteLike = () => {
        const like = {
            like: this.state.like
        };
        this.setState({like: false})
        this.props.deleteLike(like);
    }

    render() {
        const like = this.state.like;
        let button;
        if (like) {
            button = <LikedButton onClick={this.handleDeleteLike}/>;
        } else {
            button = <LikeButton onClick={this.handleAddLike}/>;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                {button}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

AddLike.propTypes = {
    addLike: PropTypes.any
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addLike, deleteLike })(withRouter(AddLike));
```

**LikeActions.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { toastOnError } from "../../../utils/Utils";
import { ADD_LIKE, DELETE_LIKE } from "./LikeTypes";

export const addLike = like => dispatch => {
    axios
      .post(`/api/v1/add_like/`, like)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({
          type: ADD_LIKE,
          payload: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        toastOnError(error);
      });
  };

export const deleteLike = id => dispatch => {
    axios
        .delete(`/api/v1/add_like/${id}/`)
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type: DELETE_LIKE,
                payload: id
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            toastOnError(error);
        })
}
```

The `error` when I press the `like` button:

```
# This is the JSON being logged
{post: ["This field is required."]}
# This is the error on the server
Bad Request: /api/v1/add_like/
"POST /api/v1/add_like/ HTTP/1.1" 400 36
```

The `error` when I `unlike` a post:

```
AssertionError: 'LikeViewSet' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method.
[16/Feb/2021 14:29:25] "DELETE /api/v1/add_like/[object%20Object]/ HTTP/1.1" 500 93663
```

I apologize for the length of this post - I appreciate any help provided: thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you are missing to add the post id in the payload for like button

Comment: And for deletion (unlike) you are sending the raw js object in the request. Check your frontend code to send id of like model in the url

Comment: Okay, that makes sense about submitting the post id for the like payload, so would I include the post.id somewhere in the Like model? I'm a bit confused about how I would implement what you're saying about the payload.

Comment: I believe you will be required to add {'post': post.id} in the payload when requesting to like the post

Comment: On the front end, when you are clicking the like button. That time you must be making post http request to the like endpoint

Comment: Okay, @VJMagar I added the `AddLike.js` code where the functionality for the `like` button is. Is the payload added in the constructor method, or is it added in the `handleAddLike` function?

Comment: I am not familiar with react.js as I use vue.js myself. Let me still try to help you out with this. Can you share the code of addLike and deleteLike which is been imported form likeActions `import { addLike, deleteLike } from "./LikeActions";`

Comment: @VJMagar just added the `LikeActions.js` file.

Comment: post(`/api/v1/add_like/`, like), in this like object only have like key value, update this like object to have post: post.id instead of like: ture

Comment: Okay that makes sense, so just so we're on the same page, I'm changing the `post(/api/v1/add_like/, like)` to `post(/api/v1/add_like/, post)`, correct?

Comment: const like = {
            like: this.state.like
  }; Update this to const like = { post: <id of post> }

Comment: @VJMagar okay, I implemented those changes. However, still getting some errors - I don't want to take too much of your time though. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating separate model for Like you can link your User model with `ManyToMany` relationship to the Post Model like this.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True,related_name='likes')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created_at',)
```

And you can make your own APIView for likes and unlikes.

For eg.

```
Class AddLikeUnlikeView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    def post(self,request,post_id):
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
        if post.likes.filter(pk=request.user.pk).exists():                                                              
            post.likes.remove(request.user)
        else:           
            post.likes.add(request.user)  
        return Response..
```

urls.py

```
path('like/unlike/<int:post_id>', AddLikeUnlikeView.as_view(), name='like_unlike')
```

OR if you want to stick with your current Model

```
   def post(self,request,post_id):
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
        if Like.objects.filter(post=post, created_by=request.user).exists():
           Like.objects.filter(post=post, created_by=request.user).delete()                                                       
        else:           
            Like.objects.create(post=post,created_by=request.user)  
        return Response..
```

Comment: Okay that is a good solution. Just to clarify, how does this fit with the frontend files `AddLike.js` && `LikeActions.js`?

Answer (score 0):

In  PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet), remove queryset or get_queryset

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)
```

We are required to define `queryset` or include `get_queryset` method in the viewsets.